# Create union of interface values based on keys of another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0, union-types

I have an interface with keys as enums and further interfaces as values.

```
enum Enum {
  Val1, Val2, Val3
}
interface MyInterface {
  [Enum.Val1]: { bookingId: string }
  [Enum.Val2]: { videoId: string }
  [Enum.Val3]: { userId: string }
}
```

With them I have an associated model:

```
const EVENT_TASK_MODEL = {
  A: {
    a: [Enum.Val1, Enum.Val2],
  },
  B: {
    c: [Enum.Val2, Enum.Val3]
  }
} as const
```

Based on the above model, **I want to create a union that combines the values for each key of `MyInterface` based on the provided keys**. Something like below:

```
CombinedModel<"A", "a"> // { bookingId: string } | { videoId: string }
```

Explanation:

```
EVENT_TASK_MODEL["A"]["a"] = [Enum.Val1, Enum.Val2]
Look up values in MyInterface: MyInterface[Enum.Val1] and MyInterface[Enum.Val2]
Their values are: { bookingId: string } and { videoId }
Create union: { bookingId: string } | { videoId: string }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to create a generic type with two generic parameters `K1` and `K2`. They are constrained to be a valid path in `typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL`.

```
type CombinedModel<
  K1 extends keyof typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL,
  K2 extends keyof typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL[K1]
> = 
typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL[K1][K2] extends infer U extends readonly (keyof MyInterface)[]
  ? MyInterface[U[number]]
  : never
```

We index `EVENT_TASK_MODEL` with both `K1` and `K2` and store the result in `U`. By adding this extra `extends readonly (keyof MyInterface)[]`, we remind TypeScript what the shape of `U` should be. At last, we create a union of the tuple stored in `U` by indexing it with `number` and use the union to index `MyInterface`.

```
type T0 = CombinedModel<"A", "a">
// type T0 = {
//     bookingId: string;
// } | {
//     videoId: string;
// }


type T1 = CombinedModel<"B", "c">
// type T1 = {
//     videoId: string;
// } | {
//     userId: string;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQUoDUCGAbAjAGnWwCYDMsBmJAXyQEsQAXYAJwDMMBjYKAWQE8AkoxbsuUZKgDacSADoyOALoAucVABGAe00BregHMBAE1UBnBswNQaUmRHnEVagG60jwTcbMWrNqNPgHCicEKDBTFi8oc0sQfWtqJCQOTRBzWDQYADkAFQB9HIBBAGUAaTyeAHkAERgAGSgAXnEUKELVCVQoDFUAuQUCOyCiRTxWqjHUACEO1tQOXqGyElhAsnJFcepu0ygUtIYkpAY+AAduAGFNCHV6YCMeTXcsAB5W0pwoYAAPJhAjXY6YB8TSsKAnc6gjLZfJFMoVGr1SZQUpEL6-UAAqBAkFgiEeMEwTK5AolcpVWp1SQfTYAPiaUAAFPioUSYaT4RT6gBKalKakjdF-LH0VgsKAAVSFmN2zGAGCMqSwfCZOKh-CETDYnGAvM2qAA-LxBMJtVxJBLJPB1CxFPqoKoQMBnCwkvioDkAAwMq43O4PJ7AV4AIkKwYIwYwwdpSAA9LHwWduF6Gch411UFpdAYojEDABuOMJqhQAA+LXTGdc7k8JmiPjihfTNDdSY9n2avtuToDzxewam4agwY40aLifO7dT46rbg8uYb+ibxbLFYTGfCkTrecb46oQA)

Comment: Nice job, I was trying this: `type CombinedModel<First extends keyof typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL, Second extends keyof typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL[First]> = MyInterface[typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL[First][Second][number]];` which worked from the outside but had an error inside.

Comment: parenthesis around `typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL` are superfluous though

Comment: @GuerricP - yeah what you wrote should theoretically work too. Its just TypeScript inconveniently not knowing what the `typeof EVENT_TASK_MODEL[K1][K2]` really is.